# Signing a message with sha512 in python

Tags: python, hmac, sha512

I'm trying to send a message over a websocket at hitbtc.com. From the api documentation, "signagure" needs to be a "hash-based message authentication code: base64 hmac-sha512 (binary representation of the message)"

I'm getting the error message: 'str' object has no attribute 'hexdigest'

```
    import time
    import json
    import hmac
    import hashlib
    def sign(payload):
                key = ""
                secret = ""
                """
                Signature method which wraps signature and nonce parameters around a
                payload dictionary.
                :param payload:
                :return:
                """
                nonce = str(int(time.time() * 1000))
                package = {'apikey': key,
                           'message': {'nonce': nonce, 'payload': payload}}

                signature = hmac.new(secret, json.dumps(payload).hexdigest,
                                     hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
                package['signature'] = signature

                return json.dumps(package)
payload = {"Login": {}}
s = sign(payload)
```

Comment: Maybe it's from json.dumps(payload).hexdigest, since dumps returns a string.

Comment: Thats definitely where it is coming from.  If I change it to: signature = hmac.new(secret, json.dumps(payload),
                                     hashlib.sha512).hexdigest()
then i get another error: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'

Comment: I just copied your code to a new .py file and changed the line as you described, and it seemed to be working with no errors (http://imgur.com/a/PB1qP)